# How to change text-size with SeekBar value in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here I want to change text size with `SeekBar` in Flutter, which means when we `scroll` `SeekBar` toggle, text size also change with `SeekBar` value.

How I accomplish this?

Comment: feel free share code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a **StatefulWidget**

This should help you

```
class ChangeTextSizeWithSeekBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChangeTextSizeWithSeekBarState createState() => _ChangeTextSizeWithSeekBarState();
}

class _ChangeTextSizeWithSeekBarState extends State<ChangeTextSizeWithSeekBar> {

  double _value = 10;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "My size will change",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: _value
                ),
              ),
              Slider(
                onChanged: (value){
                  setState(() {
                    _value = value;
                  });
                },
                max: 100,
                min: 10,
                value: _value,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output:

[image]